# Discord js message doesn't fetch any messages

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am building a Discord bot where everything is configured properly but I am having a problem with fetching the message data. I am aware of the newest version of discord.js, thus I am using `messageCreate`.

I've added some console logs in order to track the errors, and seems that message sent to the server where the bot is operating - is not recognized at all by the JS script:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {

    console.log(`Received message from ${message.author.tag} in ${message.guild ? message.guild.name : 'DM'}:`);
    console.log(`Content: ${message.content}`);
    console.log(`Embeds: ${JSON.stringify(message.embeds)}`);
    console.log(`Attachments: ${JSON.stringify(message.attachments)}`);

    // Ignore messages from bots
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content === '!bitcoin') {
        try {
            const price = await getBitcoinPrice();
            message.channel.send(`The current price of Bitcoin is $${price}`);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof FetchError) {
                message.channel.send(error.message);
            } else {
                message.channel.send('An unexpected error occurred.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is clearly pointing that message data is empty:

```
Logged in as [bot-name]
Received message from [user] in [server-name]:
Content: 
Embeds: []
Attachments: []
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved an error by enabling Privileged Gateway Intents within Developer portal and expanding intents with `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent`.